# preserve input field value using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have two forms on single page one is user information form and other is promocode form. If user inputs its information and decide to apply promocode after filling their info. Than what i want is to preserve user filled info in the input field when promocode is submitted

Comment: You could POST the promotion code using AJAX, which will prevent the page from refreshing and losing your user input form.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: thank you for your response. i am calling to soap api that returns xml result to check the validity of promocode. can you explain me how to call the soap api using ajax and i am using php on serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "soap.php", // The url to your php file in the post
  data: { promocode: promocode  } // Object containing your promo code.
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Getting the error below:XMLHttpRequest cannot load "url". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: When you run this on a server it wont happen,  I assume you are running this locally?

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses but same error comes up when i runed it on server